# How to dissolve by two fields?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dissolve

I have a shapefile with many polygons in it. I want to dissolve by two fields. [image]

Is there any possible way to dissolve this by `NAMA_KPH` and `PL15_ID`?

Comment: Have you had a look at the dissolve dialogue box? It allows you to dissolve by fields, more than one too, if needed.

Answer (score 6):

As @Martin mentioned, the **[Dissolve](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm)** tool allows you to choose multiple fields to dissolve by.

Run the tool and select `NAMA_KPH` and `PL15_ID`.

[image]